# prove the following relation,

Tags: trigonometry

If $$ xy + yz + zx = 1 $$

then show that, $$\frac{x}{1-x^2} + \frac{y}{1-y^2} + \frac{z}{1-z^2} = \frac{4xyz}{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)(1-z^2)}$$

I have tried multiplying all three terms on the left side, and then solving but in vain. Then I tried, doing this,

$$\frac{xy}{(1-x^2) y} + \frac{yz}{(1-y^2)z} + \frac{zx}{(1-z^2)x}$$
but couldn't solve it further. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $x=\tan A, y = \tan B, z = \tan C$. Then 
\begin{equation*}
\tan(A+B+C) = \frac{\tan A + \tan B + \tan C - \tan A \tan B \tan C}{1-(\tan A \tan B + \tan B \tan C + \tan C \tan A)}
\end{equation*}
Since the denominator is zero, it follows that $A+B+C = (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$, where $n$ is an integer. Thus $2A+2B+2C = (2n+1)\pi$ and hence 
$\tan(2A+2B+2C) = 0$. This gives
\begin{equation*}
\tan 2A + \tan 2B + \tan 2C = \tan 2A \tan 2B \tan 2C
\end{equation*}
Now, $\tan 2A = \frac{2\tan A }{1-\tan^2 A} = \frac{2x}{1-x^2}$. Substituting in the above, the result follows.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $x = \tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't proceed with your hint.Please provide some more hints